# My model produces 1.0 training accuracy and validation accuracy, but the predicted labels are incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using the model:

```
dim = (94, 1)
x_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=dim)
x = Conv1D(10, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x_input)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(24, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(16, activation="softmax")(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x_input], outputs=[x])
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This model, when using my training data produces a 1.0 accuracy and 1.0 for testing accuracy. When I use the test data and model.predict, I dont receive the correct labels. Specifically, the labels are constant for the entire duration.

When I use model.evaluate the model correctly predicts the labels, but when using evaluate it doesn't.
the input is 7500 entries of (94,1) with 7500 outputs of (16,1). Is there an issue with the model?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 16 classes and a last layer as

```
Dense(16, activation="softmax")
```

your loss is incorrect. You should compile the model with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`. `binary_crossentropy` should be used only for single-node last layers with `sigmoid` activation.

Comment: Okay, I adjusted that. Do you have any other suggestions? The model appears to now have a loss in the millions and poor training accuracy of 0.08. Maybe a different model would work better, any suggestions for CNN models?

Comment: I changed the optimizer to SGD and now am getting NaN loss and 1.0 accuracy, however the guesses are all value NaN, so it is still not giving the correct output.

Comment: @Inexperienced_sadface in ML modelling, experiment is king, and only you can do that (we don't have the data, neither we know anything about them); only thing we can actually do here is pointing out mistakes such as the one I talk about, in order to ensure that your model is not meaningless, but we can do little else beyond that. ML modelling (especially with NNs) is largely still an art, with little to no theory to guide us.

Comment: As mentioned, my output data is of size 7000+ steps of (16,1). Each of the 16 should be a 1 or 0 to denote on or off. Am i using the proper activation functions for this? Also, I only change the size of the input data to (steps, 94, 1) and I don't change the output size. Should I change this too? (steps, 16, 1) and if so I would have to change the activation, as I received an error.